# Python differences in class definitions

Tags: python

I know the following works but i never understood what the difference are between

```
class Animal:

class Animal():

class Animal(object):
```

Is this just a style difference or something more to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, all three are the same, i.e. all derive from `object`.

Comment: Yes this is the case in Python 3, but (very importantly) this is NOT the case in Python 2, where omitting the inheritance of object creates an old-style class. As a rule of thumb, always make new-style classes in Python 2.

Comment: @UlfAslak: yes sure! In `Python 2` it was very important! As such `python 3` if very nice!